# Product detail not appearing in product page

Tags: php, content-management-system

When I am adding any product in admin side , all option are updating in product page except product detail

Here is the code for addproduct page . Please help me

```
<?php
include('includes/init.php');
checkSession();
$subcats=$superadmin->getAllSubcats();
$cats=$superadmin->getAllcats();

//$allpkgs=$pkg_class->getAllPkgs();              
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Admin Ajwa Fruit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/pro_dropline_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--  jquery core -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "code"
 });
</script>


 <!-- UploadiFy -->
 <link href="includes/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- UploadiFy Ends-->
<!-- datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/datepicker/jquery.ui.all.css">

    <script src="includes/datepicker/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/datepicker/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/datepicker/demos.css">
<!-- datepicker -->

<!-- fancybox-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
<!-- fancybox-->


<!-- MUST BE THE LAST SCRIPT IN <HEAD></HEAD></HEAD> png fix -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


        $( "#eventdate" ).datepicker();

          jQuery('#logout').mouseover(function(){

        jQuery(this).css('cursor','pointer');

         })
 jQuery('#logout').click(function(){




         //ajax
          $.ajax({
                    type    : "POST",
                    cache   : false,
                    url     : '<?='logout.php'?>',
                    data    : '',
                    success: function(data) 
                      {
                         if(data =='1')
                        {

                            window.location = "index.php";
                            //alert('hi');
                        }

                      }


                });

          //ajax


         })

         //uploadify

 $('#mainimage').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'includes/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'includes/uploadify/mainuploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'includes/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : 'images/event_imgs/',
    'auto'      : false,
    'width'      : 128,
    'height'      : 128,
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
    'fileDesc'    : 'Image Files',
    'buttonImg'   : 'images/uploads-icon.png',
    'multi'     : false,
    'onSelect'    : function(event,ID,fileObj) {

            var nooffiles = parseInt($("#mfcounter").val())+1
                      $("#mfcounter").val( nooffiles)
                      //alert($("#mfcounter").val());
            },

            'onCancel' : function(event,ID,fileObj,data) {
                      var nooffiles = parseInt($("#mfcounter").val())-1
                      $("#mfcounter").val( nooffiles)
                      alert('The queue has been cleared.');
            },

            'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

             //  var responseparts = response.split("|");
                 $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                 alert(response);
                 window.location.href="products.php";

            }
  });


         //uploadify

        jQuery('#btn_add').live('click',function(){


                $.fancybox.showActivity();
             $.ajax

            ({

                    type    : "POST",

                    cache   : false,

                    url     : $("#formID").attr('action'),

                    data    : $("#formID").serializeArray(),

                    success: function(data) 

                    {

                          var response = data.split("|")
                          if(parseInt($("#mfcounter").val())>0)
                           {                        
                            $('#mainimage').uploadifySettings("scriptData", {'id':response[1]});
                            $('#mainimage').uploadifyUpload();
                            // alert(response[1]);
                           }
                           else
                            {alert("Record added successfully.");
                             window.location.href="products.php";

                            }   




                          //location.reload();

                    }





                });



            }) 

            jQuery('#maincat').live('change',function(){
                  var val=jQuery('#maincat option:selected').val();
                //  jQuery('#subcatdiv').html(val);

            //ajax
                  $.ajax({
                            type    : "POST",
                            cache   : false,
                            url     : 'getsubcats.php',
                            data    : 'id='+val,
                            success: function(data) 
                              {

                                jQuery('#subcatdiv').html(data);

                              }


                        });

          //ajax


                })


});
</script>
</head>
<body> 

<!-- Start: page-top-outer -->
<div id="page-top-outer">    

<!-- Start: page-top -->
<div id="page-top">

    <!-- start logo -->
    <div style="float:left; padding-top:10px;">
    <img src="../images/logo.png" width="219" height="66" />
    </div>
    <!-- end logo -->

    <!--  start top-search -->
    <div id="top-search"></div>
    <!--  end top-search -->
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- End: page-top -->

</div>
<!-- End: page-top-outer -->

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................................................................. START -->
<div class="nav-outer-repeat"> 
<!--  start nav-outer -->
<div class="nav-outer"> 



        <!--  start nav -->
        <?php include('menu.php'); ?>
        <!--  start nav -->

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--  start nav-outer -->
</div>
<!--  start nav-outer-repeat................................................... END -->

 <div class="clear"></div>

<!-- start content-outer ........................................................................................................................START -->
<div id="content-outer">
<div id="content">

    <!--  start page-heading -->
    <div id="page-heading">
        <h1>Add new Product</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- end page-heading -->

  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content-table">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowleft.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
      <th class="topleft"></th>
      <td id="tbl-border-top">&nbsp;</td>
      <th class="topright"></th>
      <th rowspan="3" class="sized"><img src="images/shared/side_shadowright.jpg" width="20" height="300" alt="" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tbl-border-left"></td>
      <td><!--  start content-table-inner ...................................................................... START -->
        <div id="content-table-inner">
          <!--  start table-content  -->
          <div id="table-content">
            <!--  start message-yellow --><!--  end message-yellow -->
            <!--  start message-red --><!--  end message-red -->
            <!--  start message-blue --><!--  end message-blue -->

            <!--  start product-table ..................................................................................... --><!--  end product-table................................... -->
              <form action="postdata.php" method="post" id="formID">

            <input type="hidden" name="mfcounter" value="0" id="mfcounter" />
            <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th height="40" align="left">Product Title:</th>
            <td> <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="edata[event_title]" id="etitle" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <th height="41" valign="top" align="left">Product Detail:</th>
            <td> <p>
              <textarea class=""  id="edesc" name="pdata" ></textarea>
            </p>
              <p> <span style="font-size:10px; color:#F00">Leave blank detail if category for product</span> </p></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <th height="45" align="left">Category:</th>
          <td><select class="styledselect" name="edata[maincategory_id]" id="maincat">
             <option value="0">Select</option>
                      <?php
                             if(is_array($cats))
                             {foreach($cats as $eachcats)
                               {

                                  echo "<option value='".$eachcats['id']."'>".$eachcats['cat_name']."</option>";

                               }
                             }

                        ?>


          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th height="45" align="left">Sub Category:</th>
          <td>
          <div id="subcatdiv">
          <select class="styledselect" disabled="disabled" name="edata[category_id]">
             <option value="0">Select</option>
                      <?php
                             if(is_array($subcats))
                             {foreach($subcats as $eachcat)
                               {

                                  echo "<option value='".$eachcat['id']."'>".$eachcat['title']."</option>";

                               }
                             }

                        ?>


          </select>
          </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Price:</th>
            <td><!--<input type="text" class="inp-form" name="edata[edate]" id="eventdate" />-->
            <input type="text" class="inp-form" name="edata[price]" id="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th height="57" align="left">Upload Image:</th>
            <td valign="bottom"> 
             <input type="file" name="mainimage" id="mainimage"/>
            </td>
        </tr>


          <th></th>
          <td><input type="button" class="form-submit" id="btn_add" value="Add New User" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form></div>
          <!--  end content-table  -->

          <!--  start paging..................................................... --><!--  end paging................ -->
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--  end content-table-inner ............................................END  --></td>
      <td id="tbl-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="sized bottomleft"></th>
      <td id="tbl-border-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
      <th class="sized bottomright"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<!--  end content -->
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--  end content-outer........................................................END -->

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- start footer -->         
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
<!-- end footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner please help me in this regard

Comment: print_r($_POST) in postdata.php and make sure whether submitted page is getting product details or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen all the rest of the fields names are an array eg edata[]  and pdata is not an array format.

Comment: Hi Rabia i just used the plain php and changed <input type="submit" class="form-submit" id="btn_add" value="Add New User" /> from button type to submit and you can see in the print_r($_POST)    .The result is showing the pdata fields which is for Product Details            Array ( [mfcounter] => 0 [edata] => Array ( [event_title] => 132312 [maincategory_id] => 0 [price] => 131231 ) [pdata] => 12312 )